# Python smtplib connect error 10060

Tags: python, flask, smtplib

I have an error I do not understand using smtplib. 
I'm on windows 10, and in the cmd window I have set :

```
set MAIL_SERVER=smtp.googlemail.com
set MAIL_PORT=587
set MAIL_USE_TLS=1
set MAIL_USERNAME='my-gmail-username'
set MAIL_PASSWORD='my-gmail-password'
```

In Python 3.6 I'm doing the following :

```
from flask_mail import Message
from app import mail
msg = Message('test subject', sender='my-gmail-adress',recipients=['my-gmail-adress'])
msg.body = 'text body'
msg.html = '<h1>HTML body</h1>'
mail.send(msg)
```

I get the following error in the console : 
"...
File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 254, in _init__ raise SMTPConnecterror(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError:  (421, b'Cannot connect server 2a00:1450:400c:c04::10 (2a00:1450:400c:c04::10:587), connect error 10060')

Note : i have authorized gmail to use "less secure apps" as needed.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Is your host IPv6 enabled?

Comment: Thanks max for your help, Avast email agent was blocking smtplib.

Comment: Why would that need a -1 ? Was that question referenced somewhere else on stack ? What's the issue here ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved : Avast email agent needs to be disconnected.

Comment: my exact issue was solved instantaneously cuz of this. Thanks!